# Getting null object reference error while inserting data to Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**

Getting an error message saying of null object reference:

**Error**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.movies4u, PID: 4783
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.movies4u.activity_register.addNewUser(activity_register.java:242)
> at com.example.movies4u.activity_register.lambda$doRegister$2$com-example-movies4u-activity_register(activity_register.java:141)
> at com.example.movies4u.activity_register$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onSuccess(Unknown Source:8)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)

**RealtimeDatabase**

[image: Text]

**javaCode**

```
public void addNewUser(String curr_userId,String email, String username){
        User user=new User(email,username);
        userID=curr_userId;
        if(userID!=null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "adding user to database, userid-"+userID+"email-"+email+"username"+username);

            myRef.child(activity_register.this.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                    .child(userID)
                    .setValue(user);

            UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(username, username);
            myRef.child(activity_register.this.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
                    .child(userID)
                    .setValue(settings);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "user is null");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> ATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.movies4u, PID: 4783 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Because you are calling the `.child()` method on a `DatabaseReference` object that is null. So most likely you forgot to initialize it. To solve this, please add the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

As a global variable inside the class where you're having the `addNewUser()` method.

Comment: Hey Nithin. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?